# Crash on stl string assignment NDK

Tags: android, stl, android-ndk

My code crashes here:

```
void setText(const string & s) 
{ 
    needsReload = true; 
    _text = s; //<-- SIGSEGV here
}
```

`_text` is a std::string

This makes absolutely no sense. `this`, `_text` and `s` are in valid memory. I can't try portstl because I need exceptions. There is simply nothing that can go wrong. I'm currently compiling for armeabi-v7a.
Any suggestions?

After some more fiddling I discovered that it crashes whenever I assign something to a string that was the empty string beforehand. I think it has something to do with my libstdc++. Here are my compilation and linking flags:

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Mathrix.dir/main.cpp.o
/opt/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++   -DMathrix_EXPORTS -DANDROID -D__ARM_ARCH_5__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5T__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5E__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5TE__ --sysroot=/opt/android-ndk/platforms/android-9/arch-arm -fsigned-char -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -fPIC -Wno-psabi -frtti -fexceptions -marm -Os -finline-limit=64 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-omit-frame-pointer -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG -DDEBUG -fPIC -isystem /opt/android-ndk/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include -isystem /opt/android-ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/include -isystem /opt/android-ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi-v7a/include -I/home/da_petcu21/src/Porkholt/Examples/Mathrix/../../Engine/include -I/home/da_petcu21/src/Porkholt/Examples/Mathrix/../../Engine/../Externals/lua/src -I/home/da_petcu21/src/Porkholt/Examples/Mathrix/../../Engine/../Externals/libpng -I/home/da_petcu21/src/Porkholt/Examples/Mathrix/../../Engine/../Externals/zlib -I/home/da_petcu21/src/Porkholt/Examples/Mathrix/../../Engine/../Externals/uremote/include -I/home/da_petcu21/src/Porkholt/Examples/Mathrix/../../Engine/../Externals/openal-soft/include    -o CMakeFiles/Mathrix.dir/main.cpp.o -c /home/da_petcu21/src/Porkholt/Examples/Mathrix/main.cpp
Linking CXX shared library ../libs/armeabi-v7a/libMathrix.so
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/Mathrix.dir/link.txt --verbose=Yes
/opt/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++  -fPIC --sysroot=/opt/android-ndk/platforms/android-9/arch-arm -fsigned-char -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -fPIC -Wno-psabi -frtti -fexceptions -marm -Os -finline-limit=64 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-omit-frame-pointer -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG -DDEBUG -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--no-undefined   -shared -Wl,-soname,libMathrix.so -o ../libs/armeabi-v7a/libMathrix.so CMakeFiles/Mathrix.dir/main.cpp.o -L/opt/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/user/libs/armeabi-v7a -L/home/da_petcu21/src/Porkholt/Examples/Mathrix/build-android/armeabi-v7a/CMakeFiles/ndklibs/armeabi-v7a -L/home/da_petcu21/src/Porkholt/Examples/Mathrix/build-android/libs/armeabi-v7a -lPorkholt -llua -Wl,-rpath,/opt/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/user/libs/armeabi-v7a:/home/da_petcu21/src/Porkholt/Examples/Mathrix/build-android/armeabi-v7a/CMakeFiles/ndklibs/armeabi-v7a:/home/da_petcu21/src/Porkholt/Examples/Mathrix/build-android/libs/armeabi-v7a
```

The build script I'm using copies `libgnustl_static` to `/home/da_petcu21/src/Porkholt/Examples/Mathrix/build-android/armeabi-v7a/CMakeFiles/ndklibs/armeabi-v7a/libstdc++.a`

I suspect it uses the one in `/opt/android-ndk/platforms/android-9/arm/lib` instead

Comment: Not enough context. The code looks innocent. The bug cannot be found using what few info you've posted.

Comment: CLearly there is _something_ that's going wrong - since it is. I agree with Seva; please post a self-contained example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that stl was linked statically with each of my libraries, thus creating copies of certain globals it required to be shared. (see [Can't load native shared library with dependencies in a native activity app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524664/cant-load-native-shared-library-with-dependencies-in-a-native-activity-app/12544815#comment16932671_12544815) for a look over my apk's library layout).

For future reference, here is a pretty good explanation on why this happens: http://www.trilithium.com/johan/2005/06/static-libstdc/

I managed to solve the problem by simply linking stl dynamically.

Comment: have to explicitly choose 'stl=c++_shared' gnustl and stlport not working for me