# Android NativeActivity that references a dynamic library fails to deploy

Tags: android, c++, visual-studio-2015, android-ndk

**The environment...**

I have a brand new Visual Studio 2015 Android NDK Solution.
This contains 2 projects (the default template code that is generated by visual studio):

- A native activity. This is where I want to put Android specific code. It has some default code which fades the screen colour between green and black.
- A 'Packaging' project to help with deployment.

I have deployed this successfully to an Intel HAXM virtual device as well as to a real device connected via USB. All good so far.

I then added an Android dynamic library project (.so) - this is where I want to put core code (platform agnostic).
I added a reference to this Core library from the native activity project.

Everything compiles and links fine. I can still create an .APK file.

Other info:

- Android SDK 5.1 (Android-22)
- Android NDK 21
- x86
- Clang 3.8
- C++ 11
- Not using Make files or Gradle

**The problem...**

Now whenever I deploy to the virtual/real device I get the following error (taken from logcat)

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.NATester/android.app.NativeActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to load native library: /data/app/com.NATester-2/lib/x86/libNATester.so
```

**Things I have tried...**

- changing the Core library to static (.a)
- checked the android device to see if the file exists - it does exist.
- Manually deploying the .APK to the android device.

Some articles have suggested using Java code to load the libraries - I want to avoid calling Java code e.g. System.LoadLibrary as this seems like a hack - I feel that it should be possible to to have a pure C++ application on android. I can't be the only person to run into this issue?!

This looks relevant but old and again an unnecessary hack for what must be very common situation
 - [Can't load native shared library with dependencies in a native activity app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524664/cant-load-native-shared-library-with-dependencies-in-a-native-activity-app)
 - https://github.com/ikonst/android-dl

For what its worth, I am a seasoned C# developer with Visual Studio (15 years). 
I therefore take a lot of things for granted when developing apps - this is my first project using C++/Android and it seems more of a manual battle to get everything to work!

Answer (score 0):

Been struggling for a while but managed to deploy the libraries, quite easy in the end.

Right click on the project [theProject (Andorid-xx)] in the Solution Explorer and select add new item, add your .so library.

Right click on the newly added library and select properties, item type should be library, set Content to Yes, this will deploy the lib.